# We need to git rid of [git]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I draw your attention to the [git](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) tag and its 27 questions.

Git is in no wise a web application. There are a number of web applications ([github](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/github), [bitbucket](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket)) with which Git can be used, and we have tags for them for questions about the web interface there, but I don't see how questions about Git can be on topic here.

Looking through the questions, I see quite a few that are also tagged [github](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/github) or [bitbucket](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitbucket). Beyond those, I see:

- Integrating Beeminder with Authorea, the latter of which is a Git service.
- A question about Gitlab, which is another Git service.
- A question about whether Dropbox uses a version-control system behind the scenes
- A closed recommendation question about where to host version control
- A question about how to watch a generic Git repository. (Should be closed as "too broad" or as a recommendation question.)
- A question about importing Google Docs revision history into a Git repository
- A question about a failure of a CLI command to push a change to Github. (Should be closed; there's no web interface involved.)
- A closed recommendation question asking for Git wikis that support MathJax

None of these questions need the [git](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) tag. Several should be closed, especially the ones that aren't asking about a web interface.

Before I rush ahead, please offer your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Since there seems to be no objection, I'll start to (slowly) get rid of the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that remains is a leftover migration stub from a rejected migration (that a moderator needs to delete) and a migration stub that will be deleted by the Roomba in a few days.